# Ubuntu Laptop as USB Speaker

Tags: usb, alsa

I want to know if it is possible to use my Ubuntu13.04 laptop as a USB speaker. I want to connect a phone(otg capable) that allows USB audio to laptop and play music so that it comes out of laptop speakers. More generally, Is it possible for a USB host to act as a USB peripheral?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a way this would be viable. Even on a hardware level, both ends are fighting to be host. It won't even handshake let alone enter into some sort of dialogue where the sound is sent to the right place.

I can think of a few alternatives:

- Software on the phone to send the sound over wifi (various vnc servers, ArkMC, Airplay, etc)
- A bluetooth receiver (A2DP) the phone connects to, line out into laptop
- A USB DAC/sound card plugged into the phone in OTG mode. This relies on the phone being able to use an external sound card.
- A male-to-male 3.5mm jack cable.

Comment: Thanks Oli. The reason I want this is, I have a single board computer which supports USB OTG. I want to make it work like a docking speaker for smartphone. I wonder how do the available docking speakers implement their functionality!?